# Why isn't clear:left; working?

Tags: html, css, css-float

I tried creating a link that changes color when you hover over it. It's a box element with a purple background that changes to fuchisa when you hover over it. It floats to the left of the page. Right next to it, I have another element, it's a link to google. The clear;left property is supposed to prevent the link from appearing next to the floating element on the left. It's not doing that. In style in head, I have

```
p.new a {
    border: 1px solid purple; 
    float: left; 
    width: 80px;
    height: 25px; 
    color: white; 
    text-align: center;
```

and

```
div.link {
 clear: left;
}
```

And this is my body.

```
<h1>Penguins</h1>

<br>
<p class="new" >
    <a href="http://www.google.com" target="_blank">Hover</a>
</p>

<div id="link">
    <a  href="Table.html">Check out the table</a>
</div>


</body>
```

[Full Code Here](http://pastebin.com/wb9FacSU)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your css selector suggestes `link` is a class name, while it is id, use `div#link` selector.